# Error while compiling cursor in plsql block

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table as employee. I am new to oracle.I am creating the cursor but when I compile,I get error:

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR c_data IS 
    SELECT distinct dept_id 
      FROM offc.employee; 

    tmp_event offc.employee.dept_id%type; 

BEGIN 
    OPEN c_data; 

    LOOP 
        FETCH c_data INTO tmp_event; 
      EXIT WHEN c_data%NOTFOUND; 

        Dbms_Output.Put_Line(tmp_event.dept_id); 
    END LOOP; 

    CLOSE c_data; 
END;     
/
```

I got the error as follows:

> Error at line 1 **ORA-06550:** line 15, column 40: **PLS-00487:** *Invalid*
>   *reference to variable 'TMP_EVENT'* **ORA-06550:** line 15, column 9:
>   *PL/SQL: Statement ignored*

I think there is problem in **tmp_event** declaration.How to handle this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Dbms_Output.Put_Line(tmp_event);`

where `tmp_event` is a variable which is already of type `offc.employee.dept_id%type`

<kbd>[This link](https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-cursor-with-parameters/)</kbd> would help for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query

```
DECLARE 
        CURSOR c_data IS 
          SELECT distinct dept_id 
          FROM   offc.employee; 
        tmp_event offc.employee.dept_id%type; 

    BEGIN 
        OPEN c_data; 

        LOOP 
            FETCH c_data INTO tmp_event; 

            EXIT WHEN c_data%NOTFOUND; 

            dbms_output.Put_line(tmp_event); --Dont Use Dept id
        END LOOP; 

        CLOSE c_data; 
    END; 

    /
```

Answer (score 0):

The following PL/SQL statement is equivalent to the original statement, but way shorter and thus less prone to programming errors.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_data IS
    SELECT DISTINCT dept_id 
      FROM offc.employee;

BEGIN
  FOR r_data IN c_data LOOP
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r_data.dept_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```